# Scrape Google Trending Stories Page (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all the top 50 searches on the Google Trending Stories page found here: https://www.google.com/trends/

However, when I run the following code, none of the searches show up and it looks like I am only getting Tags:

```
wikis = ["https://www.google.com/trends/"]
for wiki in wikis:
    website = requests.get(wiki)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "lxml")
    text = ''.join([element.text for element in soup.body.find_all(lambda tag:    tag != 'script', recursive=False)])
    new =  re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z \n]','',text)
```

Output:

```
MyAccountSearchMapsYouTubePlayNewsGmailDriveCalendarTranslatePhotosMoreShoppingWalletFinanceDocsBooksBloggerContactsEven more from GoogleSign inYou are using unsupported browser Some features may not work correctly Upgrade to a modern browser such as Google ChromeTrends has upgraded to a newer version which is not supported by this devicedismiss
```

Any help?

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that https://www.google.com/trends/ is Javascript generated. So you can't use `requests` that is an http lib.

To test web sites in your browser with Javascript disabled : example for firefox :

```
about:config

javascript.enabled = false
```

Check google/SO to find Javascript capable libs

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Dev Tools *Network Tab*.
2. Click on *Fetch/XHR*.
3. Find Name with the response you want (click on some name and hit *Preview*), in my case, it was: `topdailytrends?hl=en-US&tz=-180&geo=UA`.
4. Make a `requests.get()` to that URL that you'll see in the *Headers* tab after clicking on the name, in my case, it was: `https://trends.google.com/trends/api/topdailytrends?hl=en-US&tz=-180&geo=UA`.

Example code:

```py
import requests, json

response = requests.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/api/topdailytrends?hl=en-US&tz=-180&geo=UA').text.replace(")]}',", "").strip()

json_data = json.loads(response)
trending_searches = json_data['default']['trendingSearches']

print(json.dumps(trending_searches, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

----------
'''
[
  {
    "title": "З днем Ангела Марії",
    "formattedTraffic": "10K+",
    "trendingSearchUrl": "/trends/trendingsearches/daily?geo=UA#%D0%97%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%97",
    "country": "Ukraine"
  }
...
]
'''
```